# Azure MSBuild.exe not respecting 'NoWin32Manifest'

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-pipelines, clickonce

I have `ClickOnce` app and I want to generate `.application` file for every version without manifest. I've set

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In the project file, but when building through `Azure Pipelines` with `MSBuild` there is no `.application` file for the version generated

I've also tried to set `/p:NoWin32Manifest=true` but still nothing.

Why is that?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

`NoWin32Manifest` this property applies only to Visual Studio projects targeting Windows Vista. In projects deployed using **ClickOnce** and Registration-Free COM, this property is **ignored**.

This is stated in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019).

[image]